# Can I say 'a guy or girl' instead of 'a guy or a girl'?

Tags: grammar, articles, conjunctions, grammaticality-in-context, indefinite-article

When asking someone's sex online, we can ask 'are you a guy or a girl'. But is it correct to ask 'are you a guy or girl'?

Comment: I think both are fine, but for some reason repeating "a" in this particular example sounds better to me.

Comment: @cruthers I posted an answer but I have weird examples. Can you provide better examples please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think strictly it should be 'a' for both.

- Eg 'I have a pet.' / 'Is your pet a dog or a cat?'

I think also this is to account for plurals.

- Eg 'Do you have a dog or 2 cats?'
- Eg 'Would you rather have a slice of cake or an ice cream cone?' vs 'Would you rather have a slice of cake or 2 ice cream cones?'

P.S. I know my examples are weird. Lol.